# Appropriate use of python3 format function

Tags: python-3.x

I saw the following example of the appropriateness of the code.

```
for (i in 0 until stack.size)  # bad
while (!stack.isEmpty)  # good
```

In this perspective, What's the best code in my situation.

In Byte-of-python, the format function is said to simplify code, but I wonder if reckless use is more harmful.

```
START_TIME = time.time()
time.sleep(1)
END_TIME = time.time()

print("spend time : {time}".format((END_TIME - START_TIME) = 'time') 
# Why is this a grammatical error?

print("spend time : " + str(END_TIME - START_TIME ))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The str.format method provides readability to code, especially when you need to insert things in the middle of strings. Imagine you want to construct a string that reads "The weather is {sun_status} today with a high of {high_temp}, a low of {low_temp}, and a {percip_chance}% chance of rain". Writing it out using string concatenation would be very ugly...

```py
s1 = "The weather is " + sun_status + " today with a high of " + str(high_temp) + ", a low of " + str(low_temp) + ", and a " + str(percip_chance) + "% chance of rain."
```

The str.format method cleans this up and takes care of all the str type casting for you (if you need it)

```py
s1 = "The weather is {sun_status} today with a high of {high_temp}, a low of {low_temp}, and a {percip_chance}% chance of rain"\
     .format(sun_status=sun_status, 
             high_temp=high_temp,
             low_temp=low_temp, 
             percip_chance=percip_chance)
```

There is also an error in your code. when you call the str.format method, the keyword can be whatever you placed in the curly braces {} and is not enclosed with strings. It must also come first.

```py
print("spend time : {time}".format(time = (END_TIME - START_TIME)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `print` statement is missing a bracket at the end, and this is the correct syntax:

```
print("spend time : {time}".format(time = END_TIME - START_TIME))
```

Note that you can simplify this to:

```
print("spend time : {}".format(END_TIME - START_TIME))
```

Or using [f-strings](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings):

```
print(f"spend time : {END_TIME - START_TIME}")
```

Using `format()` or f-strings instead of string concatenation is generally preferred for readability. It also allows you to combine different data types without having to cast them to a string first.

Comment: The short-form of format() is something I've never seen before but I'll definitely be using it in the future. Thanks for the info!